# apply() not assigning values

Tags: r, apply

I have a subset of a data frame of 16 columns. They are all factors, with the same levels and labels. I am trying to use one of the `apply()` functions to assign the levels and labels at once, but my function is printing the results rather than assigning them to the data frame. I could write them all out individually - there are only 16 - but I have larger groups of variables later to make factors so this would save me a lot of work.

Example data:

```
df <- structure(list(col1 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L), col2 = c(0L, 0L, -1L, 0L, -1L, -1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), col3 = c(-1L, 
1L, 1L, -1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, -1L, -1L), col4 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), col5 = c(-1L, -1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, -1L, 0L, 1L)), .Names = c("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", 
"col5"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

With this data I've tried:

```
levels <- -1:1
labels <- c("Don't know", "Not mentioned", "Mentioned")
lapply(as.list(1:5), function(x){
  df[, x] <<- factor(df[, x], levels = levels, labels = labels)
})
```

This prints each variable rather than assigns it to the original data frame, and also incorrectly makes all cells `NA`. Clearly I am doing something wrong but I can't see what (maybe I've not had enough coffee).

My question is: how can I assign the levels and labels to multiple variables simultaneously, probably with a `xapply()` function.

I've seen [this post on R Bloggers](http://www.r-bloggers.com/quick-tips-within-function-assignment-and-specific-object-removal/) so have used `<<-` instead of `<-` but to no avail, and I've also tried `assign()` without an luck, either.

Thanks.

Comment: When I run your code I get a dataframe containing the values "Don't know", "Not mentioned", "Mentioned". Isn't that what you're trying to achieve? The values in your original `df` are overwritten with the 3 string values.

Comment: Modifying global environment from within a function is asking for trouble. You could do `df[] <- lapply(df, factor, levels = levels, labels = labels)` instead.

Comment: Thanks for looking in to this. The reproducible example I've provided is working with your suggestions while my actual data is not. I'm going to look in to this and perhaps amend my example data or try to find out why my actual data isn't working. I am after factors, ideally.

Comment: I've managed to apply (see what I did there) @DavidArenburg's suggestion to my original data (see accepted answer). Curious why modifying global environment is asking for trouble though; is that not what you do when you assign a value outside of a function anyway? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by @DavidArenburg, there are better ways to do this.

If you are really after `factor`s, then you can do as @David recommended:

```
df[] <- lapply(df, factor, levels = levels, labels = labels)
```

The `[]` preserves the structure of the input while assigning the value returned from the function/s you've applied.

---

If you are mostly concerned about just getting a character representation of these values, you can try something different, like this:

```
df[] <- labels[match(unlist(indf), levels)]
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to modify this slightly to make changes to my original data set. I used `df[] <- lapply(df[, a:b], factor, levels = levels, labels = labels` where `a:b` are values assigned to relevant column numbers.

Comment: @Phil, It really should be `df[a:b] <- lapply(df[a:b], ...)`, right? (I've left out the comma because you're dealing with a `data.frame` not a `matrix`, so the comma is not *necessary* (though it doesn't hurt either).

Comment: Actually both work but `df[, a:b] <- ...` took less time (although not significantly on a >~3,000 variable dataset).

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be trying too hard to use an `apply()` based approach when simple subsetting might be much easier to implement:

```
df[,][df[,] == -1] <- "Don't Know"
df[,][df[,] == 0] <- "Not Mentioned"
df[,][df[,] == 1] <- "Mentioned"
```

If you had a longer list of recoding over multiple values you could easily put this in a loop over your lookup value vector and replacment vector.

Comment: This is a very elegant solution, very worthy of an up-vote! I'll marked the `apply` solution as accepted because that is technically the answer to the asked question, but this is probably the better solution to my actual problem so I will probably use this method. Thanks!